# Dynamic Auto Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, constraints

To everyone who reads it. I want to make chat application like Viber, WhatsApp, etc. And the main problem for me is dynamic design. I know how to work with constraints if user interface is stick but, if it is changing, I don’t.
Please, look at the animation from Viber:
[image: Viber chat screen]
Everything is moving and changing when typing and receiving or sending messages. How to do it using Autoalyout? Especially I am interesting how to do it with UITextView. To expand it when typing, and, what is more important, how to move table view above it. Maybe, change size of parent view which holds text view. I think all this stuff can be call Dynamic Auto Layout.
I will appreciate any help or advice!
I am using Swift and Xcode 7, all latest versions.

Comment: UIStackView is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that builds a keypad using UIStackViews. The layout is managed by UIStackView.

```
func newPad(runModeVariable:Int) {


    var xPos:CGFloat = 0
    var yPos:CGFloat = 0

    keyPadWindow = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: 320, height: 356))

    var keyCount = 0
    keyPadSV = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 356))
    keyPadSV!.axis = .Vertical
    keyPadSV!.spacing = 0.0
    keyPadSV!.alignment = .Center
    keyPadSV!.distribution = .EqualSpacing
    for _ in 0 ..< 5 {
        let keyPadSVB = UIStackView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        keyPadSVB.axis = .Horizontal
        keyPadSVB.spacing = 0.0
        keyPadSVB.alignment = .Center
        keyPadSVB.distribution = .EqualSpacing
        for _ in 0 ..< 4 {
            let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
            button.tag =  keyCount
            let blah = "x" + String(keyCount)
            let blahIMAGE = UIImage(named: blah)
            button.setImage(blahIMAGE, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.keyPadPress(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            keyPadSVB.addArrangedSubview(button)
            keyCount += 1
        }
        keyPadSV.addArrangedSubview(keyPadSVB)
    }
    keyPadWindow.addSubview(keyPadSV)
    self.view.addSubview(keyPadWindow)
}
```